# Link to a file that will later be published c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

So i'm making a program that has a table adapter for an access database. Once the user is done entering information, I added a button so they can open the DB in access and make a report with the access report wizard.

currently im using this to open the DB.

```
enter Access.Application oAccess = null;
        // Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
        oAccess = new Access.Application();
        // Open a database in exclusive mode:
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\me\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\dbapp\dbapp\mydb.accdb", true);
        oAccess.Visible = true;`
```

What i don't know is when i publish the app with the database included, how can i link the button to the published version of the database?

Comment: You'll need to get the path where the database is deployed on the server.  You may need to create various configuration for LOCAL,DEV,PROD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have to use a fully qualified path to the database in your code; the OpenCurrentDatabase function will probably accept a relative path instead.  So, for example, if mydb.accdb is going to be in the same folder as your executable, then this would probably work instead:

```
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("mydb.accdb", true);
```

or, as another example, if you wanted to put your database in a subfolder named Data within the executable's folder:

```
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"Data\mydb.accdb", true);
```